# Is there a job title for someone who only designs internal work?

Tags: designers

I have an employee whose role has evolved over time. She now works almost exclusively on internal jobs such as designing presentations for pitches, internal posters, designing our business cards and any other work that the agency requires that isn’t client work.

Her role is not reflected in her title or job description, and we are considering seeing whether she would like to make a change to her title and job description to match the role she is actually performing. What title and job description would be suitable for such a role?

Comment: What you are describing would be roughly 80% of the positions designers fill. Most designers work on company items, not client work.

Answer (score 6):

What is wrong with "designer", "graphic designer", "graphics manager"? She is an in-house designer, but designer nevertheless.

Answer (score 4):

Another common position for this kind of job is a **designer for corporate communications** (typically abbreviated to corporate-comms). Corporate comms have a wider responsibility than marketing. While marketing tend to only focus on advertising, corporate comms produce artwork for seminars, documentation, presentations, charity events etc.

But as others have said, the title would still be "designer".

Answer (score 3):

At any ol' company, they would be called an *in-house designer* but that likely wouldn't be their job title. They'd still be titled *designer*--it's just that they'd be working on an in-house team.

At an agency, however, I don't think this person would have any specific title. They're doing the same work as everyone else it seems--it's just that they have one client.

You could call them:

- in-house designer
- dedicated client support
- presentation designer
- marketing materials designer

But, honestly, I'd just ask her if *she* wants a new title and if so, what it should be. I have a hunch she'd prefer the standard title all her peers receive.

UPDATE:

On second read, it really sounds like this person is essentially working on corporate marketing and that they're supporting the marketing needs of the company. I'd simply call that *graphic designer, marketing department*

Comment: I don't agree with this. In-house designer could be working on anything that isn't being contracted to an outside designer. Basically all ad agency designers are in-house designers but if one or two are responsible for the agency's marketing as opposed to the clients then the use of "Internal" in their title is a pretty common thing.

Comment: @Ryan huh. I've never heard that as part of a person's job title. I'd personally find it odd.

Comment: Its not as common but in this case sounds like what the person is after. Can Google it to find it, here's one company looking for an Internal Marketing Manager at the moment: https://www.healthcaresource.com/dupagemd/index.cfm?fuseaction=search.jobDetails&template=dsp_job_details.cfm&cJobId=100573&source=Indeed.com

Answer (score 3):

[Internal Marketing](http://www.marketingteacher.com/internal-marketing/) or [Internal Communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_communications) would be the most common titles.

My technical title is Marketing Content Creator for HR purposes though we don't use any titles in practice.

Comment: Both of those refer to having a customer base of internal employees, though. The OP is talking about a role that would be creating materials for both internal and external audiences. The more I think about it, it really sounds like the role is standard 'marketing'. They are helping the firm with its marketing materials.

Comment: oh agreed its either Internal Marketing or just Marketing Creator. Especially in a Graphic Design / Ad Agency a way to distinguish the person working on the agency's own marketing vs the people working on client projects can be handy. @DA01

Answer (score 1):

The confusing thing about titles is that they often incorporate rank, job duty, and focus. In more absurd cases, you'll see something like "Corporate Vice-President for Corporate Communications" (a genuine position at Microsoft), but in this case you could call her something like Sr. Graphic Designer for Internal Projects. Really, the second part is extraneous in many cases.

I think the tough part of this is not how you will title her role, but how you might advertise it if you were aiming to replace her. There, you'd need to explain that although this is an agency, this particular role is only for internal projects.

In my opinion, the Senior designation is fitting for someone who can manage an entire project, looking after the multiple steps and phases involved in getting something created and sent out for printing. It has more to do with independence and skills for self-reliance rather than years in the role.